# CSS Grid unintended gap

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-grid

## Background

- I'm making a form with react and tailwindCSS

## Problem

[image]

Here is my code.
(gap-y-12px => this is my custom tailwind configuration)

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-y-12px gap-x-20px">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="om-checkbox "><input id="domestic" type="radio" name="domestic"><label for="domestic" class="om-checkbox__label">Love</label></div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="om-checkbox "><input id="foreign" type="radio" name="foreign"><label for="foreign" class="om-checkbox__label">Friend</label></div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="om-checkbox "><input id="both" type="radio" name="both"><label for="both" class="om-checkbox__label">KiWi</label></div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="om-checkbox "><input id="none" type="radio" name="none"><label for="none" class="om-checkbox__label">Orange</label></div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="om-checkbox "><input id="other" type="radio" name="other"><label for="other" class="om-checkbox__label">HAHAHA</label></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to remove the unintended gap in .om-checkbox ?

(I don't want to wrap div for making two rows)

-- Edited --

This is codepen link.

https://codepen.io/YOONBYEONGIN/pen/qBvOzYv

Comment: please share a working example

Comment: in your codepen example its working fine.. hope you found your solution